# Trying to convert list of dates from char to datetime to perform timeseries

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I have imported a column of dates from excel in the format 4/16/2017 11:12:04 PM. Im trying to convert it so that I can plot it. I am unsure what format the datetime needs to be in for a timeseries

I have tried running
as_datetime(x, tz = NULL, format = NULL)

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with the lubridate package:

```
library(lubridate)

mdy_hms("4/16/2017 11:12:04 PM")
```

Comment: Thank you this worked however when I try to apply this to the whole column, mdy_hms(x), I get an error back that says "All formats failed to parse. No formats found.[1] NA"